# Groovy classpath issue

Tags: groovy, rsyntaxtextarea

I have run the following code in this page [RsyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/examples/example1.php) using Java and i run the program exactly the way that is been mentioned in this site.And i'm getting the output as intended. But i have tried to modify this java code to Groovy code, something like:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.*
swing =  new SwingBuilder()
frame = swing.frame(title : "test", defaultCloseOperation:JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, pack:true, show : true, size :[100,100])
{
        panel
        {
             RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea();
             textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
        }
}
```

And when i try to run this script as follows:

```
groovyc -classpath rsyntaxtextarea.jar TextEditorDemo.groovy
```

I get the errors stating that:

```
groovy: 9: unable to resolve class RSyntaxTextArea 
 @ line 9, column 19.
        RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea();
                     ^

/home/anto/Groovy/Rsyntax/ST.groovy: 9: unable to resolve class RSyntaxTextArea 
 @ line 9, column 30.
        RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea();
                                ^

/home/anto/Groovy/Rsyntax/ST.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class RSyntaxTextArea 
 @ line 10, column 7.
         textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
```

I guess i have made wrong in running the program. How i do i run the program in this case by defining the classpath too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're importing the package for RSyntaxTextArea.  Have you tried adding the following imports to your program?

```
import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.*;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.*;
```

Comment: it works but, i couldn't get the `RsyntaxTextArea` in my Swing. I'm getting only the frame and its title!

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want...  You needed to add the `RSyntaxTextArea` into the view (using the `widget` method)

You also needed to add it into a `JScrollPane`, so that it scrolls nicely when full.

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import java.awt.BorderLayout as BL
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.*

RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea()
textArea.syntaxEditingStyle = SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA

swing =  new SwingBuilder()
frame = swing.frame(title:"test", defaultCloseOperation:EXIT_ON_CLOSE, size:[600,400], show:true ) {
  borderLayout()
  panel( constraints:BL.CENTER ) {
    borderLayout()
    scrollPane( constraints:BL.CENTER ) {
      widget textArea
    }
  }
}
```

**edit**

Without using widget, your code would need to look something like this:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import java.awt.BorderLayout as BL
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.*

RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea()
textArea.syntaxEditingStyle = SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA

swing =  new SwingBuilder()
frame = swing.frame(title:"test", defaultCloseOperation:EXIT_ON_CLOSE, size:[600,400], show:true ) {
  borderLayout()
  panel( constraints:BL.CENTER ) {
    borderLayout()
    sp = scrollPane( constraints:BL.CENTER )
    sp.viewport.add textArea
  }
}
```

Comment: what is a widget? Could you explain me this?

Comment: Why should i use widget rather than including those statements in `panel` closure? Reason's....

Comment: @ant Because if you don't use `widget`, it won't work.  The `widget` call basically says "Add a component which isn't defined in the SwingBuilder"

Comment: Actually, the above comment is misleading as I believe you could store your `scrollPane` into a variable (lets say `sp`), and then later call `sp.viewport.add( textArea )` to add your textArea into it, but if you use widget, your code can be somewhat cleaner

Comment: @tim : So , since `RsyntaxTextArea` is not defined in `swingBuilder` i can't use it directly correct?

Comment: @ant Not sure what you mean...  You need to create a `RSyntaxTextArea` instance and then add this to the SwingBuilder.  This is either done via the `widget` method, or the Swing `parent.add` method directly.

Comment: @tim : Can you specify some tutorial links for `SwingBuilder`, because i need to know more about it, since i'm working with `RsyntaxTextArea` to create a simple programming editor...